# Get Class of an Object From Superclass in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, superclass, static-variables

Constant properties are static properties(belongs to classes, not instances) in Matlab, like many other OOP languages. And natural way to access them is `ClassName.PropName` as in [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/properties-with-constant-values.html).

However, I couldn't find a way to do `ClassName.PropName` from a superclass, in a scenario like this:

```
classdef (Abstract) Superclass < handle
    properties(Dependent)
        dependentProperty
    end

    properties (Abstract, Constant)
        constantProperty
    end

    methods
        function result = get.dependentProperty(obj)
            c = class(obj); % Here I have to get class of obj
            result = length(c.constantProperty); % to use here as `ClassName.PropName`
        end
    end
end



classdef Subclass < Superclass
    properties (Constant) 
        constantProperty  = [cellstr('a'); cellstr('b')];
    end
end
```

so that following commands results following outputs this:(**expected output**)

```
>> subclassInstance = Subclass()

subclassInstance = 

  Subclass with properties:

     constantProperty: {2×1 cell}
    dependentProperty: 2

>> subclassInstance.dependentProperty

ans =

     2

>>
```

But instead, I get following this:(**actual output**)

```
>> subclassInstance = Subclass()

subclassInstance = 

  Subclass with properties:

    constantProperty: {2×1 cell}

>> subclassInstance.dependentProperty
Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

Error in Superclass/get.dependentProperty (line 13)
            result = length(c.constantProperty);

>>
```

Also tried: `c = metaclass(obj)` which gives "No appropriate method, property, or field 'constantProperty' for
class 'meta.class'."

**Question:** Is there any way to obtain class of an object from superclass, to be able write a statement like `ClassName.PropName`?

---

EDIT:

I know I can reach from object reference like this:

```
function result = get.dependentProperty(obj)
    result = length(obj.constantProperty); 
end
```

But this is not what I want as it makes reader to think `constantProperty` is an instance property. Also this is not documented in Matlab, instead documentation says `ClassName.PropName` and this makes me think that there must be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *right* way to do this in matlab is through the instance, as per the part of my previous answer you have now incorporated in your question. This is because matlab's object-orientation model is "instance" based.

The constant property *is* an instance property; it just happens to be the same (i.e. constant) in all instances. Presumably, this is why it's called "constant", not "static": it does not refer to a single static item in memory, like in c; instead every instance is instantiated with that same constant value.

You gain nothing by going out of your way to call it via a "class reference" (no such thing exists btw; unlike python and julia, class prototypes are not objects that can be referred to, nor do they have a type themselves).

However, if you insist, there *does* happen to be a way to do this using metaclasses, since a constant property set from within the constructor will have a default value named in its metaclass profile

```
subclassInstance = Subclass();
m = metaclass(subclassInstance);
mp = findobj (m.PropertyList, 'Name', 'constantProperty');
mp.DefaultValue
```

---

Also, to address why `class(subclassInstance).constantProperty` doesn't work, this is simply because the result of `class(subclassInstance)` is a *string* (whose value happens to be the classname), not a "reference" to a class (like I said, such a thing doesn't exist in matlab).

However, if you wanted to, obviously you could use such a classname *string* within an eval statement, to evaluate it as if you were typing it directly in the terminal to access the constant property. So this is another way of achieving what you're after:

```
eval([class(subclassInstance) '.constantProperty'])
```

but in theory `eval` statements should generally be avoided unless there's no alternative.

---

<sub>Short note:</sub>

> in Java this is possible by this.getClass()

In java this is called [reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html), and it's java's own mechanism for 'inspecting' objects. When you do something like `myObject.getClass()`, what you're returning is *still* not a "reference to a class prototype". It's an *instance* of type `Class`. I.e. even in java, you can't do `myObject.getClass().aStaticProperty`. But you *can* use the `getFields` method provided by the `Class` class to obtain `Field` objects, and inspect their value with respect to specific object instances; for static fields, this instance simply becomes the `null` object.

Comment: I know that I can reach from object. However Matlab documentation tells me that I can reach from class reference. Plus, reaching from object is ugly, makes reader think that `constantProperty` is an instance property. Also, in Java this is possible by `this.getClass()` and that makes me think that there must be a way.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully this helps explain things better. tl;dr: there _is_ a way, but it's not the way to go. Use the object, Luke!

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/matlab-vs-other-oo-languages.html says "Static properties are not supported. See persistent variables. **For the equivalent of Java static final or C++ static const properties, use Constant properties.** See Properties with Constant Values" . But yes `findobj` method is way more uglier, I better use object reference.